# Writing a loop that will repeat itself "N" times as decided by the user

Tags: java, loops, average, probability

I need to write a program for Java that "rolls" two 6-sided die and that keeps track of how many tries it took to roll a 7. The program also needs to run this process N number of times, determined by the user. After the Nth trial, the program needs to compute the average amount of trials it takes to roll a 7.

I'm pretty confident that I should use a while loop inside of a for loop but I'm unsure of exactly how to do it. I already have written the code to a program that "rolls the dice," and is shown below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class RollDice {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        String input = "";
        do {
            System.out.println("Rolling the dice...");
            System.out.println("You rolled a"+((rand.nextInt(6)+1)+(rand.nextInt(6)+1)));
            System.out.println("Roll again? (y/n)");
            input = keyboard.next();
        } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

Yes, I know it's a do-while loop, but it's all I have so far.

Comment: Add some code in your preferred language to start with.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask questions.

Comment: my guess is you will roll 2 dice? otherwise how will you roll 7.

Comment: Updated the post to be more specific, the preferred language is Java and yes I meant two die.

Answer (score 0):

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31980/a-simple-dice-roll-game

This would be a great place for you to start. Then just add a second die, and a variable for the average. But please do not copy this code directly. Use it as a template/guideline. I want no part in plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I failed to mention when I first posted that the code needs to be in java and involve a while loop inside of a for loop

Comment: That is still an easy fix. Just use the code given as pseudo code. And follow the template. The whole loop/for loop is a trivial change.